# Display Magento order comments in print.phtml (customers prinable order)

Tags: magento

Just wondering if anyone has any idea how to show comments on the customers printable order - http://www.mydomain.com/sales/order/print/order_id/48/

I can see the file that I need to edit is “/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/sales/order/print.phtml” but am unsure what code I need to add to display the comments.

FYI: We are using this extension to make the order comments box show up on the order page - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/10860/. The order comments are successfully displayed on the order email but we need them be be displayed on the customers order pages as well.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Should also add that we are using Magento 1.6 community ;)

Comment: Did you get what you need? @MWD

Answer (score 6):

+1 for code_break, who answered this nicely. Here's my own version for completeness:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('pending','processing'));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $orderComments = $order->getAllStatusHistory();

    foreach ($orderComments as $comment) {
        $body = $comment->getData('comment');
        if (strpos(strtolower($body),'some text') !== false) {
            // do something cool here...
        }
    }
}
```

Use as you wish. Hope it helps.

Comment: My comment is null, even though there's text in it. Maybe it's because of status = pending?

Comment: Any help  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334  thanks @Jongosi

Answer (score 4):

The last post used the getVisibleStatusHistory method of the order object, but the first comment entered on an order is never visible. There are several methods for grabbing the status history and setting it in the order object.

That being said we might want to list all of the comments that are marked as visible on front-ed and the first comment entered when the order is created. I've substitued your formatting with a `<p>` tag.

```
<?php $_history = $order->getAllStatusHistory(); ?>
<?php $_buffer = array(); ?>
<?php $_i=1; ?>

<?php foreach ($_history as $_historyItem): ?>
    <?php // Ignore the visibility for the first comment ?>
    <?php if ( $_historyItem->getData('is_visible_on_front') == 1 || $_i == count($_history) ): ?>
        <?php $_buffer[] = $_historyItem->getData('comment'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $_i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if ( count($_buffer) > 0 ): ?>
    <p><?php echo implode( $_buffer, '</p><p>' ); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are asking especially for the oder comment from MageMaven OrderComment this would be the easiest solution:

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($_order->getCustomerNote()); ?></p>
```

Comment: Any help  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334  thanks @Eydamos

Answer (score 0):

Hey try adding this code I havent tested it but i have a feeling it will work for you:

```
<?php $_history = $_order->getVisibleStatusHistory() ?>
                                                    <?php if (count($_history)): ?>
                                                    <div class="order-additional order-comments">
                                                        <dl class="order-about">
                                                            <?php foreach ($_history as $_historyItem): ?>
                                                                <dd>
                                                                    <span class='lowcase'><?php echo $_historyItem->getComment()?></span>
                                                                </dd>
                                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                        </dl>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php endif?>
```